# Gifu not showing image

Tags: swift, animated-gif

I'm trying to load a gif and animate it using Gifu. When trying to do so the gif is not shown `GIFImageView()` does exist since it can be noticed when changing the background color and I checked that I am adding the gif from its relative path. Below is the loading gif variable and the function

variable:

```
 lazy var loadingGif:GIFImageView = {
    let view = GIFImageView()
    view.frame = CGRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 50, height: 50)
    view.animate(withGIFNamed: "art.scnassets/ripple")
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    return view
}()
```

relative function:

```
    func configure(iconVal:String?){
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .regular)
    self.blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    self.blurEffectView!.frame = self.view.frame
    self.view.insertSubview(self.blurEffectView!, at: 0)

    self.view.addSubview(loadingGif)
   
    
}
```

the function `configure` is called from its superview